# Finding the potential difference across RC circuits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

Sorry for asking a homework question, I know you guys get pissed off from them. But I need help as I seem to be misinterpreting a Kirchhoff's rule concept
[image]

It says the current goes left, so traversing from left to right IR + Q/C + emf = +19V. Is apparantly wrong. My understanding of the kirchoff's rule is that if the current is against the way you traverse the circuit u add the voltage hence the +IR +Q/C; for the battery, the traversion ends at it's positive end so +emf. Which part of my interpretation was wrong?

Comment: Look which side of the capacitor has the positive charge.

Comment: This is a DC current, which does not flow through a capacitor. Therefore there should be no voltage dropped by the resistor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important clues are the direction of the current, the $+$ and $-$ signs on the capacitor and the orientation of the battery symbol.

Stating at node **b** and passing through the battery there is a drop in potential of $8.0 \, \rm V$.

Now passing through the capacitor, going from a $-$ to a $+$ the potential increases by $5.0 \, \rm V$.

Now passing through the resistor to node **a** the potential must drop by $6.0 \, \rm V$ because the direction of the current through a resistor is always from a higher potential ($+$) to a lower potential ($-$).

The potential diagram is shown below and from it you can find the potential of node **b** relative to node **a**:

[image]

Comment: Wait so i wasnt supposed to traverse it from left to right? How come?

Comment: @Prandals To get the potential diagram you can do it whichever way you like. However to get the answer for the potential of node b relative to nade a you start on the left and go to the right.

Comment: Oh was mistake when I said the voltage thru capacitor is positive?

Comment: so like the correct from left to right should be: +IR - Q/C  + emf = +9V